# Javascript replace nested array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of sections as below. I want to dynamically replace any of these section's object at a time and want to kind of do a deep replace.

All of these have a unique section Id.
So, I have a "section" object with id and I want to replace and return back the "sections" array with the replaced object within it. Rest of the array objects should retain their values.

```
"sections": {
    "section-1": {
        "id": "section-1",
        "fields": [
            {
                "id": "fld1",
                "mandatory": true,
                "visible": true,
                "maxLength": 10,
                "items": [],
                "gridItems": [{
                    "fields": [{
                        "id": "nestedFld1",
                        "mandatory": true,
                        "visible": true,
                        "maxLength": 0,
                        "items": [
                            {code: "SELECT", displayText: "Select"}, 
                            {code: "PRIMARY",displayText: "Primary"}
                        ],
                        "value": "Nested 1",
                        "disabled": false,
                        "hidden": false,
                        "readonly": false,
                        "fieldLabel": "Type",
                        "regex": "",
                        "fieldType": "dropdown",
                        "editable": true
                    }, {
                        "id": "nestedFld2",
                        "mandatory": true,
                        "visible": true,
                        "maxLength": 0,
                        "items": [
                            {code: "SELECT", displayText: "Select"}, 
                            {code: "PRIMARY",displayText: "Primary"}
                        ],
                        "value": "Nested 2",
                        "disabled": false,
                        "hidden": false,
                        "readonly": false,
                        "fieldLabel": "Type",
                        "regex": "",
                        "fieldType": "dropdown",
                        "editable": true
                    }]
                }],
                "value": " 123",
                "event": null,
                "disabled": false,
                "hidden": false,
                "readonly": true,
                "fieldLabel": "Fld 1",
                "regex": "",
                "editable": true
            },
            {
                "id": "fld2",
                "mandatory": false,
                "visible": false,
                "maxLength": 0,
                "items": [
                    {
                        "code": "Select",
                        "val": "Select"
                    },
                    {
                        "code": "Opt1",
                        "val": "Opt1"
                    }
                ],
                "value": null,
                "event": null,
                "disabled": false,
                "hidden": false,
                "readonly": false,
                "fieldLabel": "Origin Status",
                "regex": "",
                "editable": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "section-2": {
        "id": "section-2",
        "fields": []
    },
    "section-3": {
        "id": "section-3",
        "fields": []
    }
}
```

In above example, I have shown section-2 and section-3 as quite empty, but they'll have similar structure as section-1

Comment: Are you at liberty to change the data structure? This would be a lot easier if it were a nested object instead of an array of objects. In a nested object with keys like "section-1" you could just use the spread operator.

Comment: Oh k...Actually, I would have preferred array, but yes, I entirely have the flexibility to change the data structure if that would make it easier

Comment: Post the actual JavaScript that you tried to use as a [mcve] and we'll fix it for you. If you don't have any JavaScript then we can assume that you want us to do all the work for you?

Comment: @copenndthagen if you need to access the data as an array to iterate over in the UI you can always use Object.values() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Comment: @NeilGirardi: I have updated the question showing nested object instead of arrays...Hope this one is more easier...Please suggest.

Comment: Can you give an example for how the response should be if section 1 -> grid item-> fields  is changed will the whole obj should change or jus the only object that was changed should be returned

Comment: So, I want the output in the same exact format i.e. with "sections": {}....Only thing is I would want "section-N" object to be replaced "entirely" with whatever object I'll provide...

Comment: I am not sure if I do response.sections[sectionId] = replacementSection;            , will that replace or merge...since I do not want to merge, but replace the individual section object entirely

Answer (score 0):

```
    const sections = {
  "section-1": {
    "id": "section-1",
      "fields": [
      {
        "id": "fld1",
        "mandatory": true,
        "visible": true,
        "maxLength": 10,
        "items": [],
        "gridItems": [{
          "fields": [{
            "id": "nestedFld1",
            "mandatory": true,
            "visible": true,
            "maxLength": 0,
            "items": [
              {code: "SELECT", displayText: "Select"},
              {code: "PRIMARY",displayText: "Primary"}
            ],
            "value": "Nested 1",
            "disabled": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "readonly": false,
            "fieldLabel": "Type",
            "regex": "",
            "fieldType": "dropdown",
            "editable": true
          }, {
            "id": "nestedFld2",
            "mandatory": true,
            "visible": true,
            "maxLength": 0,
            "items": [
              {code: "SELECT", displayText: "Select"},
              {code: "PRIMARY",displayText: "Primary"}
            ],
            "value": "Nested 2",
            "disabled": false,
            "hidden": false,
            "readonly": false,
            "fieldLabel": "Type",
            "regex": "",
            "fieldType": "dropdown",
            "editable": true
          }]
        }],
        "value": " 123",
        "event": null,
        "disabled": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "readonly": true,
        "fieldLabel": "Fld 1",
        "regex": "",
        "editable": true
      },
      {
        "id": "fld2",
        "mandatory": false,
        "visible": false,
        "maxLength": 0,
        "items": [
          {
            "code": "Select",
            "val": "Select"
          },
          {
            "code": "Opt1",
            "val": "Opt1"
          }
        ],
        "value": null,
        "event": null,
        "disabled": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "readonly": false,
        "fieldLabel": "Origin Status",
        "regex": "",
        "editable": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "section-2": {
    "id": "section-2",
      "fields": []
  },
  "section-3": {
    "id": "section-3",
      "fields": []
  }
}

const updatedSections = {
  ...sections,
  'section-2': {
    ...sections['section-2'],
    fields: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  }
}
```

I'm using spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax. In the example above, I created a new object which clones the existing object but updates the `fields` of `'section-2'`